# Is it appropriate to use multiple hosts within one .NET program?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, architecture

I'm coding a bot with a web interface, and I'm wondering whether it's appropriate for me to use multiple hosts within one program to host the two separate background tasks - the bot's long-term functionality, and the web server for the web frontend.  I've created a solution with a bootstrap project and separate projects for the bot and web parts, and put the following in my bootstrap project's `Main`:

```
var botHost = Bot.Service.HostSetup
    .CreateHost(args, _serviceName, _serviceDescription);
var webHost = Bot.Web.WebHostSetup
    .CreateWebHost(args);

await botHost.StartAsync();
await webHost.StartAsync();

await Task.WhenAll(new Task[] { botHost.WaitForShutdownAsync(), webHost.WaitForShutdownAsync() });
```

I'm not sure whether this is a supported workflow, though.  The problem I'm coming across is that I want to be able to shut down the entire application from just one host.  I've tried pulling in `IHostApplicationLifetime` into the `Service` host's `BackgroundService` and calling `.StopApplication()` and it only stops `botHost` but not `webHost`.  Is there a way I can get this to work or am I only ever supposed to have one host for a program?

Comment: Just use one host and add all the services you need together.

Comment: Yeah but then the host would probably have to be a web host, which kinda feels inappropriate because the main part of the program is a bot service and the web part is just a UI add-on.